# Not able to run already compiled .so file in android studio project

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I was able to successfully run my project in Eclipse. But when i am trying to upgrade my project to Android studio it stopped working for me. I have tried every thing but it is not working. Below is my build.gradle file code.

```js
apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = false
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }
}

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    if (android.productFlavors.has('armv7')) {
        println('computedArmv7VersionCode=' + android.productFlavors.armv7.versionCode)
    }
    if (android.productFlavors.has('x86')) {
        println('computedx86VersionCode=' + android.productFlavors.x86.versionCode)
    }
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    def versionCodeOverride = cdvVersionCode ? Integer.parseInt(cdvVersionCode) : null
    def minSdkVersionOverride = cdvMinSdkVersion ? Integer.parseInt(cdvMinSdkVersion) : null

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode versionCodeOverride ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode") + "0")
        if (minSdkVersionOverride != null) {
            minSdkVersion minSdkVersionOverride
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode versionCodeOverride ?: defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode versionCodeOverride ?: defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (!versionCodeOverride) {
      def minSdkVersion = minSdkVersionOverride ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
      // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
      // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
      // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
      if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
      } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
      }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }
    def storeFile = new File(privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', signingConfig.keyPassword)
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', signingConfig.storePassword)
    def storeType = props.get('storeType')
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        }
    }
    if (storeType) {
        signingConfig.storeType = storeType
    }
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

Once i run the code and try to open my application custom keyboard get following exception.

```js
E/BinaryDictionary: Could not load native library jni_latinime
12-06 15:22:01.269 8412-8412/com.KGP.inputmethod.latin E/art: No implementation found for int com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary.openNative(java.nio.ByteBuffer, int, int) (tried Java_com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary_openNative and Java_com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary_openNative__Ljava_nio_ByteBuffer_2II)
12-06 15:22:01.270 8412-8412/com.KGP.inputmethod.latin D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-06 15:22:01.271 8412-8412/com.KGP.inputmethod.latin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.KGP.inputmethod.latin, PID: 8412
                                                                         java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary.openNative(java.nio.ByteBuffer, int, int) (tried Java_com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary_openNative and Java_com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary_openNative__Ljava_nio_ByteBuffer_2II)
                                                                             at com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary.openNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary.loadDictionary(BinaryDictionary.java:151)
                                                                             at com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary.<init>(BinaryDictionary.java:82)
                                                                             at com.android.inputmethod.latin.Suggest.<init>(Suggest.java:114)
                                                                             at com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME.initSuggest(LatinIME.java:494)
                                                                             at com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME.onCreate(LatinIME.java:399)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2945)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1467)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Below is my project folder structure :- 
[image]

My Class code where i am uploading lib :-

```js
static {
  try {
   System.loadLibrary("jni_latinime_moo");
  } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ule) {
   Log.e("BinaryDictionary",
     "Could not load native library jni_latinime");
  }
 }
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. I am very thankful who ever can help me out.

Comment: Did you mean `.so` file in the title? --- Are you mixing 32-bit and 64-bit, perhaps?

Comment: Oh Sorry yes i mean .so file. I am not sure whats you mean by 32-bit and 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue using this link :-

stackoverflow.com/questions/21096819/jni-and-gradle-in-android-studio